# How to calculate node delta of output neurons in Neural Network Classifier?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

[image]

How to calculate the node delta in the above case?

Comment: Read this question - https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/235528/130598

Comment: This is not a programming question, it is off-topic for SO.